# cannot access loop when using <text> in MVC4

Tags: jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two arrays-

1. for colors - `col[]`
2. for value from model- `arr[]`

Now-

```
var htmlofdiv = [];
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <text>
        htmlofdiv.push('<ul><li><a class="badge" style="background-color:"' + col[i] + '>' + arr[i] + '</a></li></ul>');
        </text>
        }
        $('#description').html(htmlofdiv);
```

Using above two arrays I am trying to create html and inserting that array in `div` `#description`.

**Problem-**

I am missing definition of array while trying to take serialize value according to loop in this string-

`htmlofdiv.push('<ul><li><a class="badge" style="background-color:"' + col[i] + '>' + arr[i] + '</a></li></ul>');`

It says- `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`

And if I don't use `text` type then It shows me `Too many characters in character literal`

How do I use this for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in your example client will receive something like that

```
var htmlofdiv = [];
htmlofdiv.push('<ul><li><a class="badge" style="background-color:"' + col[i] + '>' + arr[i] + '</a></li></ul>');
htmlofdiv.push('<ul><li><a class="badge" style="background-color:"' + col[i] + '>' + arr[i] + '</a></li></ul>');
//and so on, depending on Model.Count
$('#description').html(htmlofdiv);
```

Browser will expect that i - is js variable. If you want your example to work you should add @ to i, to show that this is server variable. Change your code to be like this:

```
var htmlofdiv = [];
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <text>
        htmlofdiv.push("<ul><li><a class='badge' style='background-color:" + col[@i] + "'>" + arr[@i] + "</a></li></ul>");
    </text>
}
$('#description').html(htmlofdiv);
```

P.S. Also there was some issues with quotes and double quotes.